# Photoshop JavaScript translation needed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I'm working with a script in Photoshop that will automatically resize all smart objects to their original sizes. I got the script from [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Photoshop/How-can-I-capture-a-smart-object-s-original-dimension-via/td-p/9679328). Kudos to [Barbara_Ash](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/7746676) for directing me to it. The script was made by [LeafArrow20](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/12165180) for Photoshop CC but I want to use it in CS6. I believe that the script needs some function/method translation but I don't know what CS6 uses. Any help translating this would be a **huge** help. Here is my refined version of the script:

```
#target photoshop
var doc = app.activeDocument;
function resizeSmartObject() {
var ref = new ActionReference();
ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ) );
var layerType = executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
if (layerType == "5") {
    var obj = executeActionGet(ref).getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("smartObjectMore"));
    with (obj) {
        var _tmp = getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("size"));
        var size = new Object({
            width:  _tmp.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("width")),
            height: _tmp.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("height")),
        });
    }
    var bounds = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
    var w_new = (size.width/(bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value))*100;
    var h_new = (size.height/(bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value))*100;
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(w_new, h_new);
    return;
} else { return; }
}
function cycleLayers (set){
     for (var i = 0; i < set.layers.length; i++){
        doc.activeLayer = set.layers;
        if(doc.activeLayer.typename == 'LayerSet'){
            if(doc.activeLayer.layers.length > 0) {
                cycleLayers(doc.activeLayer);
            }
        } else {
            resizeSmartObject();
        }
     }
}
cycleLayers(doc);
```

I'm getting errors specifically on line 25 *(`doc.activeLayer = set.layers;`)*.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in the original code, it's not supposed to work. Maybe the author forgot to post the correct answer? The good news that it's easy to fix: the line #25 should be like this:

```
    doc.activeLayer = set.layers[i];
```

Otherwise it was trying to assign a whole set to an active layer which doesn't make sense.

However, the bad news is that this script uses a variable `smartObjectMore` only available from Photoshop CC: this variable contains data about the original dimensions of the Smart Layer. So this script won't work in CS6.

But then again, there's a good news. There's a different approach to resetting smart objects which basically includes unpacking it first and then repacking again: this will work in CS6. [This script](https://scriptorator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soreset/index.html) is included in a [free pack of some other scripts](https://gumroad.com/l/scriptorator) I made. By default the script works on selected layers, but you can use the same `cycleLayers()` you have now to run it on every smart layer in the document, the code will be like this:

```
function main() {

    //determines path to the current script
    var thisScriptPath = ($.fileName).split('/');
    thisScriptPath.pop();
    thisScriptPath = thisScriptPath.join('/')

    var cycleLayers = function(set)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < set.layers.length; i++)
        {
            activeDocument.activeLayer = set.layers[i];
            if (activeDocument.activeLayer.typename == 'LayerSet')
            {
                if (activeDocument.activeLayer.layers.length > 0)
                {
                    cycleLayers(activeDocument.activeLayer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // runs sk_resetsmarts.jsx, make sure current script is in the same folder as sk_resetsmarts.jsx or manually provide a path here
                $.evalFile(thisScriptPath + "/sk_resetsmarts.jsx");
            }
        }
    };

    cycleLayers(activeDocument);
}
//main()
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("reset all smart layers in the document", "main()");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm having some trouble setting the reference path for the script. I have mine located here: `%PROGRAMFILES%\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\Scripts\Scriptorator`. I set `/Scriptorator/sk_resetsmarts.jsx` on line 23 but I get an error each time.

Comment: I don't think you can use environment variables in Photoshop scripts. Just use a full path and make sure you have `sk_libs.jsx` in the `Scriptorator ` folder